# automatic script execution in WinPE

Tags: image, windows-pe

I'm trying to instruct my image of WinPE to directly execute a script when it finishes loading. How can I do that? Do I have to modify `Winpeshl.ini` or `Startnet.cmd` or `Unattend.xml`? I have tried all of them with no result, so any help is appreciated. Thank you very much.

---

**Edit**

Thank you all for your answers. Just to clarify I have a couple of questions more. How would `startnet.cmd` look like? If I've understood well, it should be something like (now following [mh](https://serverfault.com/users/5234/mh) great advices):

```
wpeinit
cd <path>
echo Type <my_own_script> and press RETURN to begin installation.
```

or something like:

```
wpeinit –unattend=<path>\unattend.xml
```

As a side question, how can I make `my_own_script.cmd` to be executed with `unattend.xml`?

Comment: @mh: Thanks for the advice :-D So, a `startnet.cmd` looks like it should work? I tried something similar and I couldn't make work. It gave an error before WinPE finished loading...  :-o

Answer (score 1):

I've successfully used `startnet.cmd` in the past, so you may be having issues with bad paths if that isn't working for you.  Double-check where your scripts are located, and maybe try using an absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

Startned.cmd or unattend.xml

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748941%28WS.10%29.aspx

by using unattend you are (more) sure to have network connectivity when your scripts fire, AFAIK.